# How to make virtual boxes in Vagrant optional?

Tags: ruby, vagrant, vagrantfile

i got a small problem with Vagrant. 
In the Vagrant file, we defined a list of several virtual boxes that basically use the same configuration and are set up by vagrant:

```
boxes = [
{
  :name => "box1",
  :vmnumber => "1",
  :mem => "256",
  :cpu => "1"
},
{
  :name => "box2",
  :vmnumber => "6",
  :mem => "256",
  :cpu => "1"
},
...
]
```

... and in the same format a second list called `boxes_optional`. When calling `vagrant up`, for example, vagrant loops both lists and starts the VMs. So far, so good.

My problem is that I want to give the user the option to **not** start the boxes in `boxes_optional`. As far as I know you can't add more parameters to the `vagrant up` command and you can only query environment variables via `ENV[variable]`, but that's kind of inconvenient.

Is there mybe another more elegant way of making those boxes optional? I'm quite new to Vagrant and Ruby and I haven't been able to google a nice solution, so I'm basically looking for ideas here.

Thanks and best regards,

/tehK

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### updated answer

Played a little bit with vagrant, was almost writing a plugin, but found out in its source that it actually not so strict on its arguments if they go before command and prepended with dash or double dash(to differ from command).

So you need to call it as follows:

```
$ vagrant --without-optional-boxes up

# or, works too: #

$ vagrant -without-optional-boxes up
```

And now it will not bark on unknown argument while you are still able to get it from `ARGV`:

```
boxes += optional_boxes unless (ARGV[0] == "--without-optional-boxes")
```

Comment: That would be amazing. I'm trying `vagrant up without-optional-boxes` and indeed I can print out the whole ARGV array and see each parameter. 

Unfortunately all I get is "The machine with the name 'without-optional-boxes' was not found configured for this Vagrant environment." So while the parameters are parsed somehow, Vagrant tries to use them as machine names. Am I missing something?

Comment: @tehK hmm didn't thought vagrant is so strict about arguments, will look further later, maybe it's possible to add a plugin that would make unknown arguments legitimate.

Comment: @tehK updated my answer, seems to be working solution. (Also note there is [vagrant-env](https://github.com/gosuri/vagrant-env) plugin available, which loads evironment variables from `.env` file, which may be handy in some cases too.)

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to something like this:

```
boxes += optional_boxes if ENV['START_OPTIONAL_BOXES']

boxes.each |box| do
  # start box here
end
```

That way you will merge both lists into one if the `START_OPTIONAL_BOXES` env var is set, and only start the mandatory boxes if not.

Comment: Thanks for your answer.

Unfortunately, I need to do execute a specific method for the optional boxes, so I think I'll likely need two for-loops anyway. Apart from that I was looking for a solution without the need to use an environment variable (if such a solution exists)

Comment: The `optional_boxes` list will still be there if you want to iterate over it too. Don't think there's a way to pass custom command line args that you can check in the vagrantfile.